# How to use Django ORM to find dangling records?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

How would one use the Django ORM to write something similar to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM entities
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM apples WHERE apples.entity_id = entities.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM oranges WHERE oranges.entity_id = entities.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bananas WHERE bananas.entity_id = entities.id)
```

I have several meta tables that refer to an actual record with details but it's possible for those records to have *no* references, in which case they're "dangling".

The problem is that there's over 100 million records so a simple `exclude` using an `in` filter doesn't work:

```py
Entity.objects.exclude(userid__in=Apple.objects.all().values_list('entity_id'))
```

The SQL statement using `NOT EXISTS`, on the other hand, executes at lightning speed.

I'm currently on Django 2.2 (with plans to upgrade to 4.x within a year).

Comment: Please share your relevant models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Entity.objects.filter(apple=None, orange=None, banana=None)
```

This will make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s on the tables for the `Apple`, `Orange`, and `Banana` models, and then check if these are `None`/`NULL`.

It will work with the value [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) for the `ForeignKey`s from `Apple`, `Orange` and `Banana` to `Entity`. If that one is not specified, it will use the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) instead, and if that is not specified either, it uses the name of the model in lowercase, so here `apple`, `orange` and `banana`.